# What does scriptures say about doctors/Vaidya?

Tags: varna

I think Vaidya or Chikitsa Karmi is attributed to caste born from Brahman father and Vaishya mother, which is not considered as a good type of marriage ( as wife is two varna lower than the father) .

Is being a Vaidya considered as a good thing to do or a bad thing ?

Comment: In the Devībhāgavatapurāṇa, brahmaṇas are prohibited from receiving food from people like physicians, astrologers & arms-dealers who depend on others' misery for survival. However, vaidyas are on placed on the top-tier of sat-śūdras because of the priviledged access to Ayurveda, which is also considered as an Upaveda.

Comment: there is story of how Ashvini Kumaras (doctors of Devas) were not allowed to take Havis (yagna bhaga) because of their lower status. then they asked Chyavana Maharishi for help, who then amended the shastras that they can also partake Havis. In exchange, they made the rishi into young man (he was very old, and his new bride Sukanya was very young). That's how the name Chyavanprash (the ayurveda leghyam) came about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being a Vaidya is **NOT** considered a good thing as per [taittIriya samhitA kANDa vi. 4. 9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm) :

> *For them they drew this cup for the Açvins; then indeed did they replace the head of the sacrifice; in that (the cup) for the Açvins is
> drawn, (it is) to restore the sacrifice. The gods said of these two,
> 'Impure are they, wandering among men and physicians.' **Therefore
> a Brahman should not practise medicine, for the physician is impure,
> unfit for the sacrifice**. Having purified them by the Bahispavamana
> (Stotra) they drew for them this cup for the Açvins; therefore (the
> cup) for the Açvins is drawn when the Bahispavamana has been sung.
> Therefore by one who knows thus the Bahispavamana should be performed;
> verily he purifies himself. Their skill as physicians they deposited
> in three places, in Agni a third, in the waters a third, in the
> Brahman a third. Therefore one should put beside him a pot of water
> and sit on the right hand of a Brahman when practising medicine;
> all medicine he performs thereby, his remedy becomes effective.*

Comment: there is story of how Ashvini Kumaras (doctors of Devas) were refused Havis (yagna bhaga) because of their lower status, then they asked Chyavana Maharishi for help, who then amended the law that they can also partake Havis. In exchange, they made the rishi into young man (he was very old, and his new bride Sukanya was very young). That's how the name Chyavanprash (the ayurveda leghyam) came about.