# Is Ayurveda created by god?

Tags: ayurveda

Ayurveda is not considered as main veda but up-veda. Its [practitioner are also looked down upon.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54741/what-does-scriptures-say-about-doctors-vaidya)
Also Ayurveda does not cure of all types of illness and is behind Allopathy in many things.

I want to know if Ayurveda is created by god like other vedas or Is Ayurveda creation of human (or some devta like Aswini Kumar) , thus bound to have some fault.

Also a person having full knowledge of vedas will not be needing Ayurveda anyway as he can ask god to cure any disease. So, I think Ayurveda must have been creation of humans or devtas.